# How To Change Dynamic Meta Tag | But It's Not Work In View Source

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I Am Using history.pushState Method Which Change My URL and Title

```
window.history.pushState(null, response.pageTitle, curl);
```

using this : Change Meta Tag Description and Keyword

```
$('meta[name="description"]').attr('content', d.meta_disc_program);
$('meta[name="keywords"]').attr('content', d.meta_keyword_program);
```

URL | Meta Tag | Title Change dynamic by Database.
on page load or refresh - data get by match URL with database URL Field.
All work good in page.
But in **View Source** : URL Change But Not Show Any Meta Tag | Title in **View Source**

**Explain More My Question :** 
This is Dummy code Which i used - d.ProgramUrlonWeb is (**like : /b-tech-Electrical-engineering**) it generate curl(see on code)

```
//Change URL 

                            if (d.ProgramUrlonWeb) {

                                var ma   = window.document.URL;                                                        
                                var res = ma.substring(0, ma.indexOf('\search-your-course'));


                                    if (ma.indexOf('\search-your-course') != -1 && data.length > 0) {
                                        if (d.ProgramUrlonWeb != null && d.ProgramUrlonWeb != undefined) {
                                            //back slash in url
                                            if (ma.indexOf('localhost') != -1) {
                                                curl = res + 'search-your-course/programmes' + d.ProgramUrlonWeb;
                                            }                                                                                                                                           
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        if (d.ProgramUrlonWeb != null && d.ProgramUrlonWeb != undefined) {
                                            //forward slash in url
                                            if (ma.indexOf('localhost') != -1 || ma.indexOf('admission.aksuniversity.ac.in') != -1) {
                                                curl = 'search-your-course/programmes' + d.ProgramUrlonWeb;
                                            }                                                                                               
                                        }
                                    }

                                    //window.location.href="#";
                                    //dynamic url
                                    var response = {};
                                    var stateObj = {};
                                    response.pageTitle = d.meta_title_program;
                                    processAjaxData(response, stateObj, ma + curl);                                                                       
                                    $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content', d.meta_disc_program);
                                    $('meta[name="keywords"]').attr('content', d.meta_keyword_program);
                            }                           
//Change URL
```

**Next step :**  processAjaxData Change Page Title and URL by using window.history.pushState.

```
function processAjaxData(response, stateObj, urlPath) {
     var Title = response.pageTitle;
    if (urlPath != "" && urlPath != undefined) {
        window.history.pushState(null, response.pageTitle, curl);         
        document.title = Title;

    }
}
```

**on Page reload** : Match URL (**like : /b-tech-Electrical-engineering**) in database and return the all field of data base like meta tag and page data etc.

**Problem:** All Work in page also work refresh in page but when i open view source **Not Work** All Field is empty. So any solution ?.
[demo link](https://www.lpu.in/programmes/engineering/b-tech-mechanical) which i want .

Comment: “View source” functionality in browsers shows you the original HTML code received from the server; it is _not_ a live mirror of the DOM.

Comment: Why do you even want to do that? Changes in meta tags by JavaScript won't help you with SEO things as they most probably are not recognised by search engines

Comment: [Demo Link](https://www.lpu.in/programmes/engineering/b-tech-mechanical) This Is Example What i Want . It's More of  keyword ranking is good .

Comment: @misorude | Any One Have Solution

Comment: I still don’t know what the actual problem you are trying to solve with this is. Please explain that, using your own words, instead of just linking to an arbitrary site. I have no clue whatsoever what you are trying to tell us with that to begin with.

Comment: @misorude This Is Demo Link  [link](https://www.lpu.in/programmes/engineering/b-tech-mechanical)

Comment: Are you kidding me? I just told you that you should explain to us what your problem is, using your words, and _not_ by just linking to some website.

Comment: @misorude check it now i am update and explain more my question i hope you can better understand

Comment: @HerrSerker now google consider dynamic page i see lot of keyword (High Vol) work in dynamic url on some different site I hope you understand so provide me solution.

Comment: Still not much clearer, especially not what you actually want to _achieve_ by this. _“but when i open view source Not Work All Field is empty”_ - again, see my first comment, “view source” will _never_ reflect any changes you dynamically make to the DOM via JavaScript.

Comment: @satnamp - View source is not a live mirror of the dom element as misorude said.  I think this is the best answer as to why you are not seeing your changes in the view code section. Inspect the element and then you may see your "changed" meta sections

Comment: @misorude ok i understand so, what the solution ? In demo link (above i provide) its load data dynamically by using java script. but when i open view source all data still present in demo link view source. **How it's possible in dynamic page ?**   what technique (code ) they are used ?

Comment: I have no idea what data on that site in particular you are talking about.

Comment: @alpharomeo  in the Inspect the element  all change still present but i want to show in view source section. How it's possible in dynamic page ?  what the solution ?

Comment: @satnamp - I am sure one of the only ways you can achieve this is to generate this code serverside before the page is loaded at the client side. You can move the script to run before the page loads (but this is a guess and I am not sure if it will work).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, View Source is load data server side, so the solution is to load some data which are important for SEO in server-side. 
I am generating some server-side code like meta title and description and keyword and heading tag which is important for SEO. change some code - load Important SEO content before the page loads.
match URL by the database (PHP) return some SEO Tag and heading which is work in view source. I hope I am used current strategy.